# Working with raw pointers when the type is an unknown template argument

Tags: c++, templates

At the moment, we have a container class with an std array of components. The components are templated  and are derived from a non-templated base class. All goes well when calling member functions.

However, the container class contains raw pointers of the templated type T and we would like to use these pointers outside the component and container classes.

As an example, I give here an std::transform, but we use it in many places in our codebase and on APIs without vector or std support.

For now, we cast the raw pointers, but that's really bad design. We use c++14, and all components and their type are known at compile time.

Any ideas, i.e. what can we put in place of `???`?

Here is a minimal example:

Runnable and editable code also here: https://rextester.com/QLP97953

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

class ComponentInterface{
public:
    virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
    virtual void* GetPtr() = 0;
    static constexpr size_t Size() { return 10; }
};

template <class T> class Component : public ComponentInterface {
public:
    Component(const std::array<T, Size()>& arr){for(int i = 0; i < Size(); ++i) ptr[i] = arr[i];}
    void DoStuff() override { std::cout << ptr[0] << " " << ptr[1] << " " << ptr[2] << " " << std::endl; }
    void* GetPtr() override { return (void*)(ptr); }
private:
    T ptr[Size()];
};

class Container{
private:
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<ComponentInterface>, 3> components;
public:    
    Container() {
        components[0] = std::unique_ptr<Component<int> >(new Component<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}));
        components[1] = std::unique_ptr<Component<float> >(new Component<float>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}));
        components[2] = std::unique_ptr<Component<double> >(new Component<double>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}));
    }
    void DoStuff(int i) { components[i]->DoStuff(); }
    void* GetPtr(int i) { return components[i]->GetPtr(); }
    const size_t Size(int i) { return components[i]->Size(); }
};

int main()
{
    Container c;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        c.DoStuff(i);

    //Works, not a good design
    std::transform((int*)c.GetPtr(0), (int*)c.GetPtr(0) + c.Size(0), (int*)c.GetPtr(0), [](int a) -> int { return a + 1; });
    std::transform((float*)c.GetPtr(1), (float*)c.GetPtr(1) + c.Size(1), (float*)c.GetPtr(1), [](int a) -> int { return a + 1; });
    std::transform((double*)c.GetPtr(2), (double*)c.GetPtr(2) + c.Size(2), (double*)c.GetPtr(2), [](int a) -> int { return a + 1; });

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        ; // ???

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        c.DoStuff(i);
}
```

Comment: `void* GetPtr() = 0;` is "wrong" design. As all types are known, [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) seems appropriated instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 could you make an answer with the visitor pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With visitor pattern, instead of adding methods to interface:

```
class ComponentInterface{
public:
    virtual ~ComponentInterface() = default;

    virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
    virtual void Method1() = 0;
    virtual void Method2() = 0;
    virtual void Method3() = 0;

    static constexpr size_t Size() { return 10; }
};
```

Assuming you know each children type, you might do:

```
template <class T> class Component;

struct IVisitor
{
    virtual ~IVisitor() = default;

    virtual void Visit(Component<int>&) = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Component<float>&) = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Component<double>&) = 0;
};


class ComponentInterface{
public:
    virtual ~ComponentInterface() = default;
    virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
    virtual void Accept(IVisitor&) = 0;
    static constexpr size_t Size() { return 10; }
};
```

and then

```
template <class T> class Component : public ComponentInterface {
public:
    Component(const std::array<T, Size()>& arr);
    void DoStuff() override;
    void Accept(IVisitor& visitor) override { visitor.Visit(*this); }
//private:
    T ptr[Size()];
};
```

Usage would be:

```
struct IncreaseByOne : IVisitor
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator() (Component<T>& c)
    {
        std::transform(std::begin(c.ptr), std::end(c.ptr),
                       std::begin(c.ptr),
                       [](auto e) { return e + 1; });
    }

    void Visit(Component<int>& c) override { (*this)(c); }
    void Visit(Component<float>& c) override { (*this)(c); }
    void Visit(Component<double>& c) override { (*this)(c); }
};
```

and

```
    IncreaseByOne visitor;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        components[i].Accept(visitor);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54095200bb652865)

Comment: Great answer, thank you! It's too bad the IVisitor still needs a list of types it allows, but that seems unavoidable.